# redux saga unit test expected but received deep-equality error

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

Getting this error when unit testing a simple api call in redux saga.

> ● My feature › testing api call
>
> ```
> expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality
>
> - Expected
> + Received
>
>   Object {
>     "@@redux-saga/IO": true,
>     "combinator": false,
>     "payload": Object {
> -     "args": Array [
> -       Object {
> -         "completed": false,
> -         "id": 1,
> -         "title": "delectus aut autem",
> -         "userId": 1,
> -       },
> -     ],
> +     "args": Array [],
>       "context": null,
>       "fn": [Function getData],
>     },
>     "type": "CALL",
>   }
> ```

I have the api call that is set up like this.

```
import axios from 'axios';   
export default {
  json: {
    getData: () => axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos').then(res => res.data.slice(0, 1)),
  },
};
```

this api call is being used here in a redux-saga function.

**Redux-saga**

```
import {
  put, fork, takeLatest, call,
} from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { GET_DATA_SAGA } from '../actions/types';
import api from '../api';
import { fetchDataSuccess, fetchDataError } from '../actions/dataActions';

export function* getData() {
  try {
    const data = yield call(api.json.getData);

    console.log(data);

    yield put(fetchDataSuccess(data));
  } catch (err) {
    yield put(fetchDataError(err));
  }
}

export function* watchData() {
  yield takeLatest(GET_DATA_SAGA, getData);
}

export default function* () {
  yield fork(watchData);
}
```

How should i be unit testing this properly, am i missing something ?

I'm also referencing this tutorial

https://codeburst.io/how-i-test-redux-saga-fcc425cda018

**redux-saga unit test**

```
import {
  put, fork, takeLatest, call,
} from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { GET_DATA_SAGA } from '../actions/types';
import {expectSaga} from 'redux-saga-test-plan';
import { fetchDataSuccess, fetchDataError } from '../actions/dataActions';
import api from '../api';
import { cloneableGenerator } from '@redux-saga/testing-utils';
import {getData} from './data';

const testData = {
  userId: 1, 
  id: 1, 
  title: "delectus aut autem", 
  completed: false
}

describe('My feature', () => {
  it('testing api call', () => {
    // const data = getData(api.json.getData);
    // console.log(data)
    const generator = cloneableGenerator(getData)(fetchDataSuccess)
    // console.log(generator)
    expect(generator.next().value).toEqual(call(api.json.getData, testData));
  })
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your saga, you'd doing this, with no data being passed in to getData:

```
const data = yield call(api.json.getData);
```

Assuming it's correct that no data is passed in, your test will need to be updated to match, which means testData has no use. Delete testData, and modify the assertion to say:

```
expect(generator.next().value).toEqual(call(api.json.getData));
```